# Implement gaussian mixture model with stochastic variational inference

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, probability, bayesian, graphical-model

I am trying to implement Gaussian Mixture model with stochastic variational inference, following this [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume14/hoffman13a/hoffman13a.pdf).

[image]

This is the pgm of Gaussian Mixture.

According to the paper, the full algorithm of stochastic variational inference is:
[image]

And I am still very confused of the method to scale it to GMM.

First, I thought the local variational parameter is just $q_z$ and others are all global parameters. Please correct me if I was wrong. What does the step 6 mean by `as though Xi is replicated by N times`? What am I supposed to do to achieve this?

Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can grab some technique form [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture)